# how do i set the position of an element while ignoring background shape?

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to set the position of an element. This element’s background shape expands when hovered over. When I try to set the position using “top” the element moves when the background shape expands.

I think this is because the position setting sets the element based on its borders. How do I get it to ignore the  background shape so it doesn’t move when hovered over?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please show us the relevant code as any answer given without seeing the relevant context will just be a guess. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example